# MySQL ORDER BY strange sorting

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

Problem: mysql query return results in strange order, looks like random or so. But it happens only with one hosting, localhost and another one hosting working well. Wanna get - why it happens and how to prevent it.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into product (sort_order, status)
values
(0, 1),
(0, 1),
(0, 1),
(0, 1),
(0, 1);

CREATE TABLE `product_description` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into product_description
values
(1, 'product_1'),
(2, 'product_2'),
(3, 'product_3'),
(4, 'product_4'),
(5, 'product_5');

CREATE TABLE `product_to_category` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`product_category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into product_to_category
values
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(4, 1),
(5, 1);

CREATE TABLE `product_category_path` (
  `product_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `path_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_category_id`,`path_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into product_category_path values (1, 1, 0);
```

Query:

```
SELECT p.product_id, pc.product_category_id, pd.name
    FROM `product` p
        LEFT JOIN `product_description` pd ON pd.product_id = p.product_id
        LEFT JOIN `product_to_category` pc ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
    WHERE p.status = 1 AND pc.product_category_id IN (SELECT product_category_id FROM `product_category_path` WHERE path_id = 1)
    ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC;
```

On localhost and hosting result is always the same: 1,2,3,4,5. But on hosting it shows 1,3,2,5,4 or 2,1,5,3,4 and everytime new ordering. Why?

**Update**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html

http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=24

Comment: All of your `sort_order` values are `0`. The engine will return the rows in whatever order it "feels" like since it can't order them. For equal values in your `ORDER BY` clause, there's no *guaranteed* sort order result.

Comment: All of the values of sort_order is 0. You can use **ORDER BY p.sort_order, p.product_id** for preventing unwanted sorting.

Comment: 2all: I know that sort_order is 0 and all have the same, but __why__ one server returns constantly (by product_id) sorted result, when another one - randomly sorted everytime?

Comment: Which `MySQL version` on each system?

Comment: @Ravinder problem server - 5.5.32, working ok server - 5.5.30.

Comment: I am not sure if it is documented, but I feel there is an issue with `5.5.32` version. I too faced similar problem on `5.5.32`. Here is my attempt on [*`MySQL 5.5.32`*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/320d82/1) and due to its *unexpected output* in sort order, I tried on [*`MySQL 5.6.6`*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0541c/1)

Comment: @Ravinder This isn't a 'problem'. If the OP wants rows returned in a specified order then they should specify that order. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Strawberry u mean if in order by ill be field like `price` or smth, and all rows with the same price ill be sorted randomly everytime? Still no explain, why one server show different results.

Comment: @user3707466 I think Ollie Jones's explanation is good, don't you?

Comment: @Strawberry u mean its magic? `SQL systems are allowed to return result set rows in any order they find convenient` - why 4 already tested servers with mysql 5.5.3x returned same result with fixed sorting and another one returned randomly sorted result?

Comment: MySQL servers in large hosting facilities often are optimized to scale up. Part of this optimization can involve using more elaborate access methods than the community-edition stuff that's freely downloadable. You can spend as much time as you like wishing it were not so, but sort order always has been, is and will be unpredictable   unless it's fully specified by `ORDER BY`.  *Unpredictable* is a tricky concept to understand , but it's inherently part of RDMS development, especially at large scale.

Comment: @user3707466 In the Arthur C. Clarke sense of the word, yes ;-)

Answer (score 3):

SQL systems (of any make and model) are allowed to return result set rows in any order they find convenient unless you specify the order specifically. To put it another way, the order of a result set is formally unpredictable unless it's specified in `ORDER BY`. To put it a third way, on your `localhost` server, it's entirely accidental that your results are in the order you think they should be in. Tables have no inherent order.

You are really lucky your production server exposed this flaw in your query so quickly. Often developers don't find out about this stuff until their tables grow to tens of thousands of rows.

As this modification of your query shows (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/211536/2/0), all rows in your resultset have the same value of `SORT_ORDER`.

**Query**:

```
SELECT p.sort_order, p.product_id, pc.product_category_id, pd.name
    FROM `product` p
        LEFT JOIN `product_description` pd ON pd.product_id = p.product_id
        LEFT JOIN `product_to_category` pc ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
    WHERE p.status = 1 AND pc.product_category_id IN (SELECT product_category_id FROM `product_category_path` WHERE path_id = 1)
    ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC
```

**Results**:

```
| SORT_ORDER | PRODUCT_ID | PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID |      NAME |
|------------|------------|---------------------|-----------|
|          0 |          1 |                   1 | product_1 |
|          0 |          2 |                   1 | product_2 |
|          0 |          3 |                   1 | product_3 |
|          0 |          4 |                   1 | product_4 |
|          0 |          5 |                   1 | product_5 |
```

You've told SQL to order them that way. Both servers have done so.

If you need them to be ordered by `PRODUCT_ID` as well as `SORT_ORDER` just specify it (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/211536/4/0).

```
    ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC, p.product_id ASC;
```

Comment: Ok, if u want to sort by non-unique value u cant get result with fixed sorting without another one unique key on "some sql systems"?

Comment: Exactly so. Except for the part about *some SQL systems.* If you don't fully specify the sorting in `ORDER BY`, then the ordering you do get is *accidental* on **all SQL systems.**  Some of them accidentally give you the order you thought you should have. But I promise you they cannot read your mind. Just specify `ORDER BY`, OK?

Comment: Exactly not ;) To trick this `select` u just need a text field in field selection, read more about filesort() algorithms. http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=24 and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html It's not a magic as you see.